# Structure needs cleaning problem

Tags: filesystem, samba

I have a `samba` server on my raspberry with external SSD. I created ext3 filesystem on the SSD and it worls fine. But every time if I umount the SSD and mount it again I get the error `Structure needs cleaning` for all data on the SSD. What could I have done wrong when setting up or formatting?

```
[D]
  comment = Extra SSD
  path = /media/SSD_4TB/D
  browseable = yes
  writeable = Yes
  only guest = no
  create mask = 0777
  directory mask = 0777
  public = yes
  guest ok = yes
  force user = [user]
  force group = [usergroup]
```

`lsblk --fs:`

```
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
sda
├─sda1      vfat   FAT32        5CDE-5051
└─sda2
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   FAT32 bootfs 5DF9-E225                             449.1M    12% /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   1.0   rootfs 3b614a3f-4a65-4480-876a-8a998e01ac9b   33.6G    35% /
```

`sudo cat /etc/fstab`

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ac4032a9-01  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=ac4032a9-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

Comment: have you googled the error text? ... your question is not about the Raspberry Pi ... it belongs at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Why use ext3; ext4 has been Linux standard since before the Pi existed. WHY (and how)  do  you "umount the SSD". Samba has nothing to do with any problem you may have.

Comment: @Milliways i tried different types (ext4, ext3, ntfs, fat32). Just `sudo umount /dev/sXX`. I umounted because I needed to pluged off the SSD.

Comment: If I do similar things I disconnect Samba before unmounting, use umount mountpoint and I definitely never mount ANYTHING in /media which is used for the terrible automount which belongs to the file manager.